# XML in a webpage

Tags: html, xml

I need to "store" a piece of xml in my webpage. What is the best cross browser way to do this?

I would assume something like this should work:

```
<div class="curve">
    <h1>Acceleration</h1>
    <div class="xml">
      <xml>
        <coordinates>
            <x>10</x>
            <y>45</y>
        </coordinates>
        <coordinates>
            <x>20</x>
            <y>75</y>
        </coordinates>
        <coordinates>
            <x>30</x>
            <y>105</y>
        </coordinates>
      </xml>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use this to temporarily store data that is being manipulated. When saving I use jQuery to gather all data from the web page. In most cases I use data attributes but with the coordinates I choose xml blocks instead.
Any good way to store this in my DOM in a cross browser fashion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why should that work? It isn't HTML.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "store". The example you gave doesn't render except as a heading and `10 45 20 75 30 105`, but the XML tags are visible in the source.

Comment: Why not store it as a javascript variable? Just asking.

Comment: What problems are you currently encountering?

Comment: @zeropage: I could use a javascript variable, but I like to conform to all other data I store in data props of the tags, meaning i like having all data in one place - the markup.

Comment: @alohci: my problem is that the XML gets lower cased when I retrieve it with $('.xml') which results in failed serialization later on. I need to preserve the casing.

Comment: HTML is not case sensitive. Browsers will mess with the case of elements since the case doesn't matter (by definition). Some might let you access made up elements, but there is no guarantee of it. If you want to embed XML, then use an XML Content-Type and accept that it won't work on IE < 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need full HTML validity I would go for attributed hidden div elements. I've used it lots of times and it works in all browsers I've tried while being HTML 'compatible' enough for CSS and JavaScript manipulation.

```
<div class="curve">
  <h1>Acceleration</h1>
  <div class="xml">
    <div class="coordinates" x="10" y="45"/>
    <div class="coordinates" x="20" y="75"/>
    <div class="coordinates" x="30" y="105"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you place it in a hidden OBJECT element? According to the HTML 4.01 specification, "the OBJECT element, which offers an all-purpose solution to generic object inclusion".